# Select max em nested queries

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Tenho de selecionar o candidado que tem mais publicações que qualquer outro dos candidatos.

```
select candidato.nome, Count(1) as nr_publicacoes 
from candidato, cv,ficha_inscricao, publicacao_cv 
where candidato.bi = ficha_inscricao.bi and 
      candidato.bi = cv.bi and cv.cod_cv = publicacao_cv.cod_cv 
group by candidato.nome;
```

Porém quando faço o max, o Orale SQL Developer não dá resultados nem mensagens de erro. 
Não quero usar o `rownum`, o meu objetivo é resolver usando o `max`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em conversa pelo chat, a @DanielaMaia disse que não poderia ser usado ROWNUM, apenas o MAX. Portanto, a resposta original foi substituída por essa agora.

Para evitar o uso do ROWNUM, uma CTE (*Common Table Expression*) pode ser usada, como mostrado abaixo:

```
with publicacao_cte (nome,nr_publicacoes)
AS
(
    select
        candidato.nome,
        Count(1) as nr_publicacoes
    from
        candidato,
        cv,
        ficha_inscricao,
        publicacao_cv
    where
        candidato.bi = ficha_inscricao.bi and
        candidato.bi = cv.bi and
        cv.cod_cv = publicacao_cv.cod_cv
    group by 
        candidato.nome
)

select nome
from publicacao_cte
where publicacao_cte.nr_publicacoes = (select max(nr_publicacoes) from publicacao_cte);
```

Comment: Resolve, mas o objetivo era usar entender como usar o `max` em vez do `rownum`

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, veja se é isso, por favor.

Comment: Na linha 16 o identificador `nr_publicacoes` é inválido, não existe.

Comment: `nr_publicacoes` era uma variável que eu estava a tentar criar usado o `as`

Comment: @DanielaMaia, não sei como é a estrutura do seu banco de dados. Certamente é um erro pelo meu desconhecimento do seu modelo. O campo nr_publicacoes pertence ao qual tabela?

Comment: não pertence a nenhuma tabela, como poderá ver na minha pergunta, na 2ª linha estou a tentar criar essa nova variável com o comando `as`

Comment: Entendi, dessa maneira você não resolverá esse problema. Você conta o numero de publicacoes por candidato usando a tabela publicacao_cv?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31870/discussion-between-daniela-maia-and-cantoni).